# TextView some part is clickable and editable but other part is not

Tags: macos, nstextview

I have a problem with my NSTextView. My textView is selected and editable when i click on the right hand side of the textView area but the left half of my textView is not selectable. I tried to find and subView occurrence over my textView but none was present. Please guide me regarding the issue of half area not selectable. I created my textView as:

```
 textViewObj =[[MyTextView alloc]initWithFrame:titleFrame];
 textScrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:titleFrame];
 [textScrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
 [textViewObj setCellIndex:[subViewArray count]];
 [textViewObj setTextData: [textViewObj string]];
 [textScrollView setDocumentView:textViewObj];
```

Here, MyTextView is a class returning textView object. Please help me regarding the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Actually i was using multiple subViews in NIB due to which of of the view was creating problems with my textView. I just placed my textView overall subViews and my problem was resolved.